# Hash variable and array in perl is giving an awkward output

Tags: arrays, perl

I have just started with Perl scripting, while making an array and and fetching it from the hash variable. I am getting an awkward output.

Code is here:

```
%name= ( "xyz",1 ,"is",2, "my",3,"name",4);
%copy=%name;
$size=%name;
print " your rank is : $copy{'xyz'}";
print " \n";
print " the size of the array is : $size";
```

output is coming as :

```
your rank is : 1 
 the size of the array is : 3/8
```

why is the size of the array is of 3/8?

Comment: There is no array in your code. Which variable do you think is an array?

Answer (score 4):

It is internal information about the hash, please check the [perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a slash. This is pretty much useful only to find out whether Perl's internal hashing algorithm is performing poorly on your data set.

So here specifically it means that you have 8 buckets allocated in the hash and three of them are used.

To get the size use:

```
$size = keys %hash; # scalar is implicit here
print(scalar keys %hash);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out the number of keys/values by using `scalar` `keys`:

```
my %name= ( "xyz",1 ,"is",2, "my",3,"name",4);

my %copy = %name;

my $size = scalar keys %name;

print "your rank is : $copy{'xyz'}\n";
print "the size of the array is : $size\n";
```